# Determine whether $\int _{1}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\,{\rm d}x$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: integration

My task is to determine if the following function is convergent or divergent.

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}{x\sin\left(x\right) \over\sqrt{1 + x^{5}\,}\,}\,{\rm d}x$$

I have been trying to find a more easily integrable function which could be determined to belong in any of the two categories, but I have yet to succeed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** For all $x\in [1+\infty[$, $$\left\vert \dfrac{x\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\right\vert\leq \dfrac{1}{x^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: @GitGud Helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$ \left\vert\frac{x\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\right\vert \leq\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} $$

What does this bound tell us about the convergence?

Comment: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\sim \frac{x}{x^{5/2}}$.